# Violating commandments with good intentions

Tags: mitzvah, kavana-intent

The Talmud says, in two places: "Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak says: A transgression performed for the sake of Heaven is greater than a commandment performed not for its own sake." [Nazir 23b, Horayot 10b]

The discussion implies that both are OK, and that the second will eventually lead to doing mitzvot for their own sake.  But Rav Naḥman'a statement just says one is better than the other.  It does not say either is good or encouraged.  So: Is this behavior good or encouraged?

Example: On Shabbat morning in shul you hear that someone you know is recovering from major surgery alone in his apartment.  You tell yourself, "I can't let him spend Shabbat all by himself."  So you drive over to his place and spend the afternoon and evening with him, and do Havdalah with him.  Is this OK or not?  Need a one-bit answer.

Added note: I went to the suggested link, but I am still not sure I understand when avera lishma applies. The gemara clearly talks about what YOU think you are doing (your intention), not what others think or what the actual result of your action turns out to be.

Comment: The Gemara partially retracts that statement, so it reads not that it’s better, but that it’s on par with it. Considering that the Gemara brings a proof from Yael saving Klal Yisrael, I’d imagine the threshold is much higher than ordinary Bikkur Cholim for this ruling to apply; after all, even building the Mishkan doesn’t override Shabbos.

Comment: In other words, the other question is an exact dupe, but the answers there don’t satisfy you?

Comment: @DonielF -- I don't understand the answers.  They seem to say that, as long as Esther and Yael (and Lot's daughters) were saving all Israel, it's OK; if not, opinions vary.  But the gemara is clear that all that matters is your intention, not the result of your actions.  (If I BELIEVE I am saving all Israel, it's OK?)  I still don't know the one-bit answer to my question.

Comment: Never judge a question by the answers it’s received. If you don’t like the answers a question has received, you should post a bounty on it, not post the same question again.

Comment: @DonielF -- Bottom of page: "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged or ask your own question."

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4394/

Comment: @DonielF -- I just learned about "bounties".  In the spirit of the very question I asked, I think there is something unholy about answering a halachic question NOT for the sake of heaven. :-)

Comment: If it’s on this site it better not be a (practical) halachic question. :) Even so, that’s the site policy. If you disagree, ask it on Meta.

Comment: 1. Judaism has no hierarchy of Mitzvos so it is natural that one Mitzvah comes at the expense of other(s). For instance, learning Torah at the expense of honoring parents. While the Poskim offer some local solutions (like Pikuach Nefesh that overrides other prohibitions or Shabbos sacrifices in the Temple) it is hard to generalise for every special case.

Comment: The Torah is full with such examples of breaking serious Mitzvos for the sake of something bigger: Avraham taking Itzhak for a human sacrifice, Yaakov deceiving his father, taking two sisters, Moses breaking the Luchos, Ester commanding on fasting 3 days and canceling Pesach and many many more. So אם בארזים נפלה שלהבת... why can't we all?

Comment: Please note, that the result can be only be approved or rejected by G-d only  aposteriori - like with Moses - 3 things were approved and endorced by G-d and for others he got punished.

Comment: To your question, while the Halacha says one can't break Shabbos for other than Pikuch Nefesh, G-d might think that in that specific case and your specific spiritual level abd your destiny in this world, your decision would be considered a Mitzvah and you'd be rewarded.

Comment: The first sentence of my answer there addresses your specific case. This concept doesn't apply nowadays.